# URL Hashchange in Play Application fails on webapp

Tags: hash, frameworks, playframework, url-action

I have a play framework application which I add to homescreen on my iPhone. It works and looks like a charm except one thing:

If i change the URL location.hash via an anchor tag (`localhost:9000/connect/# to localhost:9000/connect/#/hashchange`), Play throws an error because the actual URL action (localhost:9000/connect/) is not found.

It shouldnt even show up because there is no request to the server. However i cant reproduce this error on iOS safari, only when i added it to the homescreen.

Maybe its the slash after the hashtag??

Thanks in advance!